# Receiving error 'Source origin is not allowed in' on amp-list load-more using load-more-bookmark

Tags: amp-html, amp-list, amp-bind

I have a working amp-list implementation using server-side filtering at https://staging.caymanmag.com/work/finding-a-job, but I'm not able to get the infinite scroll to work with the `load-more="auto"` attribute and `load-more-bookmark`.

The error I'm receiving is 'Source origin is not allowed in' but I don't receive a CORS errors when not using the `load-more` attribute.

I wonder if it's due to the bookmark value: `load-more-bookmark="meta.pagination.links.next"` being used? It looks like the `&page=2` attribute is being added to the end of the query string.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not seeing that error in Chrome. The page is valid. But I do see "Unable to load more. Retry" - is that the problem you are having?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. The error I referenced is from the Console in DevTools.  The front-end error is auto generated from the `load-more` AMP attribute when it fails.

Comment: IMHO that is a bug. Why don't your submit the condition here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues. As you can see on the site, there are several issues that relate to `infinite scroll` - I think you'll get quick attention to this issue.